# AnimatedVisibility breaks constraints in ConstraintLayout in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Edit: Also happens when I swap `ConstraintLayout` for a `Box` using alignment as well...

Seems like `AnimatedVisibility` doesn't play well with `ConstraintLayout` in JP Compose at the moment.

```kotlin
        AnimatedVisibility(
          visible = entryListState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 3,
          enter = fadeIn() + expandIn(expandFrom = Alignment.Center),
          exit = fadeOut() + shrinkOut(shrinkTowards = Alignment.Center)
        ) {
          ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(scrollToTop) {
              start.linkTo(parent.start)
              bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            },
            text = { Text(text = "TOP") },
            onClick = { scope.launch { entryListState.animateScrollToItem(0) } }
          )
        }
```

The ( TOP ) fab should appear in the bottom left corner, but instead I get [image: incorrect placement]

When I remove the `AnimatedVisibility` wrapper, everything works fine. :( I know I can work around this, but I'm curious if there's something I'm doing incorrectly with the configuration of the `AnimatedVisibility` composable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out I was thinking about `AnimatedVisibility` all wrong. It's just another Composable. I needed to lift the FAB's modifiers re: positioning to the `AnimatedVisibilty`'s modifiers.